# react-native nested viewpagers don't scrolling

Tags: android, android-viewpager, react-native, react-native-ios

I'm using [react-native-best-viewpager](https://github.com/abbasmoosavi/react-native-best-viewpager) to make a easy viewpager without too many work on some graphics stuff, but i'm in need of using nested viewpagers (One inside other), like the code below, but the problem it's that the second viewpager dont scroll, only the first one. If this was a Scrollview i would use `nestedScrollEnabled={true}`, but this is a viewpager:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import {IndicatorViewPager, PagerTabIndicator, PagerDotIndicator } from 'react-native-best-viewpager'
import { View } from 'react-native'

class MainScreen extends Component {

    _renderTabIndicator() {

        let tabs = [
            {
                text: 'Screen'
            }]

        return <PagerTabIndicator tabs={tabs} />
    }

    _renderDotIndicator() {
        return <PagerDotIndicator pageCount={1} />
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={{flex: 1}}>
                <IndicatorViewPager style={{height: 500}} initialPage={1} indicator={this._renderTabIndicator()}>

                   <View style={{flex: 1}}>
                        <IndicatorViewPager style={{height: 300}} indicator={this._renderDotIndicator()}>
                            <View style={{flex: 1}}>
                                <View style={{BackgroundColor: 'black', height: 50, width: 50}}/>
                            </View>
                        </IndicatorViewPager>
                    </View>

                </IndicatorViewPager>
            </View>
        )
    }
}

export default MainViewport;
```

(Just a example code)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Were you able to find this solution ?